# Convert to Polar $\int_0^2\int_0^x y\,\mathrm dy\, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

Change double integral to an equivalent double integral in terms of polar coordinates.
$$\int_0^2\int_0^x y\,\mathrm dy\, \mathrm dx$$
Firstly:
$$x=r\cos\phi$$
$$y=r\sin\phi$$
I am trying to think of bounds for $r$ and $\phi$ but I am having a hard time.
My guess that the bound of $\phi$ is $0\leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$. Can't really think of a good bound for $r$.

Comment: Good start is to visualize the bounds of $x$ and $y$ by drawing a quick sketch of the graphs namely $y = 0$ and $y = x$ within $0 \leq x \leq 2$.  You found the correct bound for $\phi$.  Now, you need to set the boundary $0 \leq x \leq 2$ for the graphs to find the radius.  The radius you will find is not a constant.

Comment: @user1242967 Hard to believe you can find the bounds for $\phi$ but not for $r$.

Comment: @GitGud: I find it fairly easy to believe. The bounds for $\phi$ are easily visualized, but without a sufficient amount of familiarity with trigonometry, the upper bound for $r$ is hardly simple to find.

Comment: $r = 0 \to 2\sec \phi$

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but wolframalpha says that integral doesn't converge. Probably because $\frac{\pi}{2}<2$ and $\frac{2}{cos\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{2}{0}$

Answer (score 1):

The upper bound you find for $r$ will be a trigonometric expression depending on $\phi$. Are you familiar with [SOHCAHTOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sohcahtoa#Mnemonics)? **Hint**: The adjacent side will be constant, so the hypotenuse ($r$) must vary as $\phi$ does.

Answer (score 1):

Given the value of $x$, the other variable, $y$, goes from $0$ up to $x$.  So it's between the line $y=0$ and the line $y=x$.  The line $y=0$ is the same as $\varphi=0$, and the line $y=x$ is the same as $\varphi=\pi/4$.

Next, for any fixed value of $\varphi$, you have move along the ray going from the origin to where you hit the line $x=2$, since $x$ goes from $0$ to $2$.  That's the hypotenuse of a right triangle.  The adjacent side is $2$.  So
$$
\frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{2}=\frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{adjacent}} = \sec\varphi,
$$
so $r$ goes from $0$ to $2\sec\varphi$.