# Convert to Polar $\int_0^6\int_0^y x\; \mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

How to calculate the integral

$$\int_0^6\int_0^y x\; \mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy$$

using polar coordinates?$$$$I know that $x=R\cos \theta$ and $y=R\sin\theta$ and that the Jacobian is $R$.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @alethiometryst
I tried replacing $x$ and $y$ of $R\cos \theta$ and $R\sin\theta$, just do not know how to replace the values of integration.

Comment: It looks like you'd be integrating $\theta$ from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$. The limits of $r$ change in some manner from $6\sqrt{2}$ to $6$ as you change $\theta$. Does that help?

Comment: $dA = dxdy = rdrd\theta$ where A is area,r is radius and $\theta$ is the angle.  Just another hint.

Comment: @alethiometryst I tried to do so, 
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_6^{6\sqrt2} R^2 \cos \theta\; dR\;d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/4}\left .\frac{R^3}{3}\cos\theta  \right |_6^{6\sqrt2}\;d\theta=(4\sqrt2-216)\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos\theta\;d\theta=(4\sqrt2-216)\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=4-108\sqrt2$$
but watching now, I will replace $y=\pi/4$ but in fact $y$ is a function that varies. So clearly my calculations are wrong !!

Comment: @John please look at my comment above, I marked the wrong person because I did this with your tip, but I know I was wrong, something else that can help me?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior try for $R$ the bounds $R_0=0$ and $R_1=3(2^{2/3})\sec{\theta}$. Here's a good link for a similar problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408870/double-integral-polar-coordinates.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Who in the right state of his mind would try to calculate **this** integral in polar coordinates (unless forced by an exercise?)

Comment: @PhoemueX Now that's a question that I couldn't even attempt to answer :)

Comment: @PhoemueX I am simply trying apresender polar coordinates. How to find the limits of integration. And, unfortunately, did not understand why the boundaries were the order you placed.

Comment: I broke down and answered the question below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$\int_0^6\int_0^y x\;dx dy$$

The region that's covered is the upper left half of a square, with lower left corner at the origin and side $6$ units.  This is an isoceles right triangle.

The angular part goes from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$.

At $\pi/4$, the integration of $r$ goes from $0 \to 6\sqrt{2}$.

At $\pi/2$, the integration of $r$ goes from $0 \to 6$.

In between, the integration goes from $0 \to 6/\sin \theta$.

So in polar coordinates the integral should be

$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{6/\sin \theta} r \cos \theta\; r\;dr\;d\theta.$$

Carrying this through gives the same answer as the Cartesian integral.